# What is the meaning/usage of 瞶?

Tags: kanji

I am reading a movie scenario magazine and came across the kanji 瞶 that I cannot understand.

The scenes involved are basically relationship moments between the two main characters.

Two examples with some context:

[image]

[image]

WWWJDIC does not match this kanji, though in Edict (via JWPce or Rikaichan) it says:
キ　see everything

Checking various other references were a dead end.

I realize this is probably non-standard literary usage, but please help me understand why it may have been used and any deeper meaning.
Are there better examples of the usage of this kanji?

Comment: 「みつめる」( http://yourei.jp/%E7%9E%B6%E3%82%81 )と読むのでしょうが、ぜんぜん辞書に載ってません。。

Answer (score 5):

http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E6%B5%B7%E3%82%92%E7%9E%B6%E3%82%81%E3%81%A6

「瞶る＝みつめる」です。

また、「凝っと＝じっと」だと思われますが、こちらも普通の辞書には見当たりません。

私は61歳の普通の日本人ですが、この二つの漢字は初めて見ました。

Comment: `私は61歳の普通の日本人ですが、この二つの漢字は初めて見ました。` こちらも勉強になった。

Comment: 中国人ですが、この漢字を見るのも初めてです。一般的な中国人は絶対にこの字を見た事ありません。ちなみに、中国語の字典を調べたりして、この「瞶」は「見つめる」の意味を持ってなく、唯一の意味は「盲（めくら）」です。「見つめる」の用法は日本語だけでしょう。